# primereact functionality of adding a new row in DataTable

Tags: reactjs, primereact

is there any way of adding a new row on button click in datatable in primereact like in primefaces.
i didn't found any functionality in primereact in documentation however there is option available in primefaces.
https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/datatable/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

hopefully you can find what you need here:
[primefaces.org/primereact/datatable/crud/](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/datatable/crud/)

there's a crud implementation of primereact datatable with a 'new' button, check the `saveProduct` function

Comment: Just to update the link for React https://primereact.org/datatable/#dtproducts